# Trying to do find the centroid of a section of an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, centroid

I am trying to find a way to draw a box around a section of an image in Matlab and find the centroid of that image. I would ideally want the "new" section to show up next to my original image, then I can to the centroid of that "new" image.

Here is my code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton15.
function pushbutton15_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton15 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
A = imread('PET_MRI_Brain_Tumor.jpg');
Z = imshow(A)
Ibw = im2bw(A);
Ibw = imfill(Ibw,'holes');
Ilabel = bwlabel(Ibw);
stat = regionprops(Ilabel,'centroid');
imshow(Z); hold on;
for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2),'bx');
end
e = imellipse(gca,[55 10 120 120])
BW = createMask(e,Z)
```

Here is the image that I am trying to put a mask over and find the centroid of that section.

[image]

Comment: Improving a question is good, but you should edit the old question instead of posting a new one. – I think you mean "and find the centroid of that *section*".

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting used to this haha. There is a function in matlab the allows you to "freewrite" over the image. This is different than simply putting a polygon over it. If you know of that function could you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a BW mask like this:

```
e = imellipse(gca,[55 10 120 120])
BW = createMask(e,Z)
```

or that has created with any other method (e.g. `imfreehand` or some type of segmentation algorithm), you can use 'regionprops':

`s = regionprops(BW, 'Centroid');`

If there is only one area/"region" in the BW image, the centroid is just:

`s(1).Centroid`

Comment: Ok, so now I'm trying to calculate the area inside that enclosed area.Would you know how to get a pixel^2 area calculation of that new enclosed area?

Comment: Look at the different possible methods that can be used with `regionprops`.  There are a number - area is one of them.  You can calculate it at the same time as `Centroid` using the 'basic' option - it's all in the docs.